# Xamarin how to position label to right align screen in listview

Tags: xamarin

I'm learning xamarin and all my attempts to influence the behavior of my label have failed. only my label still behaves strangely how to right align screen.
They do not change even if I put horizontalOptions everywhere, it seems to me that I just don’t know something
my ProductCard

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Notes.Models;assembly=Notes"
  x:DataType="models:Goods"
  x:Class="Notes.Cells.ProductCard">
<Frame Style="{StaticResource ProductCard}" BackgroundColor="Coral">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
            <Label
                BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                HorizontalTextAlignment="End"
                VerticalOptions="End"
                HorizontalOptions="End">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Span>
                        <Span Text=" " BackgroundColor ="Brown"/>
                        <Span Text="Price: " BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                        <Span Text="{Binding Price}" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</Frame>
```

and my ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:Notes.ViewModel"
         xmlns:cells="clr-namespace:Notes.Cells"
         xmlns:xct="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2020/toolkit"
         x:DataType="viewmodels:GoodsViewModel"
         x:Class="Notes.Views.ProductsCatalog"
         >
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewmodels:GoodsViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Normal">
            <ViewCell>
                <cells:ProductCard/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Special">
            <ViewCell>
                <cells:SpecialItem/>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
        <cells:ItemDataTemplateSelector x:Key="GoodsSelector"
                Normal="{StaticResource Normal}"
                Special="{StaticResource Special}"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<ListView
    SeparatorVisibility="Default"
    CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
    Style="{StaticResource NoteNewsListView}"
    GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding Key}"
    IsGroupingEnabled="True"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentGoods, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GoodsGroup}"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GoodsSelector}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
        <xct:EventToCommandBehavior
            Command="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
            EventName="ItemSelected" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Null}">
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="0,0,0,0" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelLarge}" Text="{Binding Key}" />
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
    <ListView.Header>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label
                Margin="80"
                FontFamily="AC"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                Style="{StaticResource LabelLarge}"
                Text="Catalog Products">
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Header>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button
                Command="{Binding LoadMoreCommand}"
                Style="{StaticResource ButtonOutline}"
                Text="Load more" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

and my styles

```
<Style x:Key="ServiceCard" TargetType="Frame">
            <Setter Property="HasShadow" 
                    Value="{OnPlatform Android=true, iOS=false, Default=true}"/>
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="20"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor"
                    Value="{AppThemeBinding Dark={StaticResource CardBackgroundDark},
                Light={StaticResource CardBackground}}"/>
        </Style>

<Style x:Key="NoteNewsListView" TargetType="ListView">
            <Setter Property="HasUnevenRows" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="SeparatorVisibility"
                    Value="None"/>
            <Setter Property="RefreshControlColor"
                    Value="{StaticResource SystemBlue}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsPullToRefreshEnabled"
                    Value="True"/>
        </Style>
```

[image: now]
[image: would be nice]

how to do like below picture?
thanks @Jason for advice to add backgroundcolor to my labels

Comment: I'd start by giving all the element and layouts in your ProductCard a unique BackgroundColor.  That will allow you to visualize how each element is laid out relative to the others and where the issue might be.  Once you've done this please post a screenshot of the actual result

Comment: coloring the stacklayouts helps too.  But I'd guess that your first StackLayout is not expanding to fill it's parent Frame.  Set the HorizontalOptions to fix that

Comment: I inserted HorizontalOptions=FillAndExpand everywhere I could, and even in ListView and template calls it didn't help. but I don't know that very well, maybe I'm doing it wrong Can you tell me exactly where to put it?

Comment: please set the bg color of the StackLayouts too and update your screenshot

Comment: I added HorizontalOptions in 2 stacklayot ​​parent elements and it works thanks now i can see them moving. but the question remains the previous one how to make everything in one line only Name was at the beginning of the line, and Price xxx at the end of the line from the right edge? I can only achieve this if I manually pad the width of the first line, say 500, or if they are on different lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create two Labels to display Name and Price.

```
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:models="clr-namespace:Notes.Models;assembly=Notes"
          x:DataType="models:Goods"
          x:Class="Notes.Cells.ProductCard">
          <Frame Style="{StaticResource ProductCard}" BackgroundColor="Coral">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label
                        BackgroundColor="Aqua"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                <Span Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource LabelMedium}" BackgroundColor="Blue"></Span>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
    <Label HorizontalOptions="End">
                        <Label.FormattedText>
                            <FormattedString>
                                
                                <Span Text="Price: " BackgroundColor="Green"/>
                                <Span Text="{Binding Price}" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                            </FormattedString>
                        </Label.FormattedText>
                    </Label>
    
            </StackLayout>
         </Frame>
```

Comment: this is what I wanted! thank you very much, I will study your code

Comment: Please accept the answer if it's works for you.